# jsf command button action triggred in refresh

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In My `.xhtml` page I have 2 `h:commandButton` elements:

```
 <h:commandButton immediate="true" lang="en" class="msbutton"  action="#{user.changeLanguage()}" value="Test1">
 </h:commandButton>
 <h:commandButton immediate="true" lang="en" class="msbutton"  action="#{user.test()}"   value="Test2">
 </h:commandButton>
```

My problem Is when I refresh my page the last button that was clicked is triggred again, and the action in the managed bean is performed.

I don't want the action to be triggred when the page is refreshed. (only to be triggred when the button is clicked).

Do I need to change something? what do i need to do inorder the page to be refreshed without triggreing the button action?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens due to form re-submission. Add this line at the end of your methods.

```
public void test() {
  .......
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("current_page.jsf");
}
```

`current_page` is the name of your current page.